# Prevent XSS attacks with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How do prevent `PHP` project with `.htaccess` file from `XSS(cross site scripting)` atacks?

Comment: `.htaccess` deals with **access** not with output, which is what XSS usually deals with. (Outputting comments from a database without escaping html)

Comment: @DaveChen `.htaccess` is just a config file.  It doesn't have to deal with anything access related at all.  But yes, it has nothing to do with preventing XSS, just as nothing server-layer has to do with preventing XSS.

Comment: @Brad - "it doesn't have to deal with anything access related at all"? Really? `.htaccess` has **everything** to do with access. You use it precisely to define who can access what, in the directory where the file is stored. Agree it has nothing to do with XSS, but it _does_ get used for access control (think `require valid-user`). See for example http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml

Comment: @Floris It doesn't.  Sure, you can put whatever directive your server supports for basic auth, but you could just as easily put any other directive in there, or none at all.  You can manage your security centrally, or in your application.  The idea that `.htaccess` has to be for authentication/authorization is just convention.

Comment: @Brad - OK I misread your comment. "Doesn't have to deal with" versus (as I read it) "Doesn't have anything to do with". Small change in words, big difference in meaning. I see what you mean now. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure your server to magically stop XSS attacks.  This is something you must do at the application layer, by escaping output properly.

Comment: Worth adding that web application firewalls (like mod_security) can help screen out malicious looking input, but it's a very thin safety net under an application.

Comment: @covener I usually don't even mention those, since folks often think, "I can install some thing and all my security problems are solved!"  It's true, they do provide some security measures, as you have said, but dangerous as you have also said as they fundamentally can't stop everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Add Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Protect against XSS attacks
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

- `1` : Enable XSS Protection
- `mode=block` : Rather than sanitizing the page, the browser will prevent rendering of the page if an attack is detected.

You can find more security related snippets [here](https://gist.github.com/rohankhudedev/ef94d6cf4322faf18535754a105ef897)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one, it's working for me**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
```